# WPF: Some textblocks in TabItem header

Tags: wpf, binding, tabcontrol

Example TabControl with TabItems "hello" and "bye"
I need see tabs headers as "hello - 22" and "bye - 33" in current case, but tabs has "hello - " and "bye - " headers.

```
               <TabControl>
                    <TabControl.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </TabControl.Resources>
                    <TabItem Header="hello" Tag="22"></TabItem>
                    <TabItem Header="bye" Tag="33"></TabItem>
                </TabControl>
```

What I have to change to get a working WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be something like:

```
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}"/>
```